# How to adjust the printarea into one paper

Tags: excel, vba

I've defined a print area in one sheet and print it out.
But this area is bigger that one paper, so it would be printed into 4 pages. 
I want to have all the contents in one page. So I've tried the code :

```
Sub PrintTable()    

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("myTable").PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$55"
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed

End With
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know which part to correct. I've used 'Record a Macro', perhaps I've deleted some important lines. So if you've some ideas please leave a note.

Comment: Looks OK from a first glance.  What specifically is going wrong?  Is the `myTable` sheet still printing on four pages?  Or is it printing on one page wide but multiple pages tall, or vice versa?  I think you might need to set only one of `FitToPagesWide` or `FitToPagesTall`.

Comment: Yes, there're still 4 pages. (the blue lines which define the edge of pages are inside the first page, which makes this page into 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it myself and this works:

```
   Application.PrintCommunication = False
   With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
       .FitToPagesWide = 1
       .FitToPagesTall = 1
   End With
   Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Without setting the

```
 Application.PrintCommunication
```

to false and true, it doesn't work. Can you try this?

Comment: That works! I've seen the mode has been chosen as 'adjust into one page'. That's what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Per [this explanation](http://blog.softartisans.com/2011/06/04/kb-fittopagestall-and-fittopageswide-settings-do-not-take-effect/), `Zoom` has to be set to `False` first.  Try:

```
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.FitToPagesWide = 1
```

in place of the two `.FitToPages` lines you have now.

**Original answer**

Per [this forum post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/625144-visual-basic-applications-fit-1-page-width-only.html#post3100782), try either

```
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = False
```

or

```
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.FitToPagesWide = False
```

in place of the two `.FitToPages` lines you have now.

Comment: Yes! That works! I don't see the reason but it works now :)

Comment: @Hiddenllyy Glad to hear it!  The updated one, with `.Zoom=False`, or one of the other ones?

Comment: I've tried the second one, and so the mode of pint was 'adjust the column'. But the first doesn't work in this case. It's strange.